# Best practice put nginx + django in AWS subnet private?public?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx

I want to put the `fargate` container which contains `django` + `nginx`

However what subnet should be used for?

At first I put this in public subnet, of course it works well.

However, is it possible to put this in private subnet with `NAT gateway`?

A few users(admin) need to access to this django, it doesn't need to get access from other users.

Comment: You probably want to ask this question on https://devops.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, you can use private+NAT.

Comment: @Marcin THank you for your comment, If so , I can access through VPC endpoint and Nat Gateway?